# Two equivalent definition of derivative, but where does the Taylor remainder come from?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, definition

A function of real variable $y=f(x)$ has a derivative $f'(x)$ when
$$(1)\qquad\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)$$
If, however, $x$ is a vector variable, $(1)$ makes no sense. For what does it mean to divide by the vector increment $h$? Equivalent to $(1)$ is the condition $$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+R(h)\:\Longrightarrow\:\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{R(h)}{|h|}=0$$
which is easy to recast in vector terms.

---

The above definition is taken from Charles Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis.

I am not sure where the Taylor's remainder came from. Especially if I were to start from $(1)$, how do I make the remainder term magically appear? Furthermore, why do we divide by the absolute value of $h$, as opposed to just $h$?

Comment: If we define $R(h)$ as $f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h$, then $(1)$ is equivalent to $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac{R(h)}{h} = 0$. I'm not sure if this is equivalent to $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac{R(h)}{|h|} = 0$, but of course it is equivalent to $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac{|R(h)|}{|h|} = 0$. The latter is used to define the derivative for vector variable functions.

Comment: @azif00 they are all equivalent because it’s a limit being equal to $0$ (once you write out the norms/absolute values in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ form, this is obvious).

Comment: Pugh put the absolute value there because there will be a $\|h\|$ in the multivariable setting.

Comment: why are we dividing by $|h|$? Because when we move over to a function with a multi-dimensional domain, $h$ becomes a vector, and there is no mathematical meaning of a scalar divided by a vector.  But, we can relate $|h|$ to the norm of a vector and have an expression that means something.